How to retrieve all sheets data from google sheets api using apache camel
I want to be able to retrieve all the sheets' (sheet1,sheet2,...etc) data from Google Sheets, not just one sheet (sheet1, in this example):
   from("timer:run?repeatCount=1")
      .to("google-sheets://data/get?spreadsheetId=1i8jAVG3r6BINzdU0NzgAIuDUuz3FiVRyFF1Wm6WQq_0&range='Camel Sheet1'")
      .log("${body}")
      .convertBodyTo(String.class)
      .process(new TransformerGoogleSheets())
      .to("file:file/Input?fileName=employee.csv")
      .log("Sucess");

I searched on Apache Camel's website but I couldn't get relevant solution.

Looks like you want to use the getBatch method instead of get:
from("timer:run?repeatCount=1")
      .to("google-sheets://data/getBatch?spreadsheetId=1i8jAVG3r6BINzdU0NzgAIuDUuz3FiVRyFF1Wm6WQq_0")
      .log("${body}")
      .convertBodyTo(String.class)
      .process(new TransformerGoogleSheets())
      .to("file:file/Input?fileName=employee.csv")
      .log("Sucess");

I didn't use the google-sheets api yet, but probably you will get a list of ranges as a response. You can then split the body with .split(body()) and then process every range like you are doing now. You should get the structure of the response by analyzing your logged ${body}.
With the batchGet method you only have to specify the spreadsheetId and you can omit the range.
https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/google-sheets-component.html#_api_data_method_batchGet
